# SSIS fails to deploy

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm using vs 2013 and trying to deploy a project to the integration services catalog on ssms 2016. I'm getting the error: 
"Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '23'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"
when I'm trying to query "operation_messages" the table is empty.
The thing is that I succeed to deployed it once, just after adding more packages\connections it started to fail.
Any idea anyone?
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWUOP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a compatibility issue with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL 2016, typically it works for backwards compatibility but forward can exhibit issues. I am currently using VS 2015 for our SQL 2016 systems and my SSIS packages. I am not necessarily familiar with your exact error, but when using different versions you can see some oddball errors.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest SSDT you will have a visual studio 2015 shell.  It is recommend that you use this rather than previous versions of VS, especially as SQL2016 is still relatively new.  MS may add more support for VS2013 but maybe not...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx